# Algorithm to divide elements into categories based on their size

Tags: algorithm, sorting, categories

I have an array of `task` objects, each with attributes `Hours_required` and `Remaining_days`. An example would be as below:

```
Task              1    2    3    4    5
Hours_required    6    6    2    3    10
Remaining_days    2    3    3    4    7
```

I want to divide the tasks among days, which have a predefined number of `Allocated_hours`.

```
Day                1    2    3    4    5    6
Allocated_hours    8    6    10   5    8    7
```

For example, Task_1 which needs 6 hours and has 2 days remaining, would be put into day_1 and day_2, 3 hours per each day. The whole array of tasks need to be sorted accordingly.

Is there an existing algorithm which would help me to solve the above problem? The closest Google gave me was [Bucket Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), but it does not divide elements as 3 and 3 for two days, as the example described.

I do not require an implementation, just an idea of a similar algorithm would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like a linear programming type of problem. Check out the symplex method: http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap7.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is a variant of task scheduling problem where every task is known in advance. It's solvable by a greedy algorithm, for example, [earliest deadline first](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling).